# iOS Autolayout: Custom vertical offset in addition to layout margin. Is it possible with visual format language?

Tags: ios, autolayout

Say I have a code:

```
let visualFormat = "V:|-[v]-|"
NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: visualFormat ...)
```

As result view `[v]` will be vertically pinned to superview margins.

Now I want always have top offset `12 points` while respecting superview margins. For example: If superview has `layoutMargins.top` equal to 8, then expected top offset of view `[v]` should be 20 (12 + 8).

```
let visualFormat = "V:|-12-[v]-|"
NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: visualFormat ...)
```

But with such visual format expression the view `[v]` has top offset stick to 12 regardless superview's layoutMargins.top value.

Ok. I can write like this:

```
let metrics = ["marginT": layoutMargins.top + 12]
let visualFormat = "V:|-marginT-[v]-|"
NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: visualFormat, metrics: metrics ...)
```

**Question**: Is the only one way to setup custom offset in addition to superview's layoutMargins by manually calculating offset and using it in `metrics`?

Why visual format expression `"V:|-12-[v]-|"` does not respect superview's `layoutMargins.top` value?

Thank you! .)

Complete sample code (Swift 3.1 Playground):

```
import PlaygroundSupport
import UIKit

class ParameterView: UIView {

   fileprivate lazy var innerView = UIView()

   required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
      fatalError()
   }

   override init(frame: CGRect) {
      super.init(frame: frame)
      addSubview(innerView)
      setupUI()
      setupLayout()
   }

   override func layoutMarginsDidChange() {
      super.layoutMarginsDidChange()
      removeConstraints(constraints)
      setupLayout()
   }

}

extension ParameterView {

   fileprivate func setupUI() {
      backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
      innerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
   }

   fileprivate func setupLayout() {

      innerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
      let views = ["v": innerView]
      let metrics = ["marginT": layoutMargins.top + 12]

      // let visualFormat = "V:|-12-[v]-|" // Not working as expected.
      let visualFormat = "V:|-marginT-[v]-|"
      var customConstraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: visualFormat,
                                                          metrics: metrics, views: views)

      customConstraints += NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|-[v]-|",
                                                          metrics: metrics, views: views)
      addConstraints(customConstraints)
   }
}

let host = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 80 + 16, height: 60 + 16))
host.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray

let view = ParameterView(frame: CGRect(x: 8, y: 8, width: 80, height: 60))
host.addSubview(view)
host.layoutIfNeeded()
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = host
print(host.perform("recursiveDescription"))

DispatchQueue.global().async {
   var isInsetsActive = true
   while true {
      sleep(1)
      DispatchQueue.main.async {
         let offsets: CGFloat = isInsetsActive ? 4 : 8
         view.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets(top: offsets, left: offsets, bottom: offsets, right: offsets)
      }
      isInsetsActive = !isInsetsActive
   }
}
```